# Структуры. С++. Не правильный вывод на экран.Ошибки

Tags: c++, структуры

1) Почему выдает 0x28fc38, а не само число? уже и тип данных меняла. Когда пишу d={{123}}, выводит: {.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <clocale>
#include <iomanip>

#define SIZE 20
using namespace std;

struct Dannie{
    int number[SIZE];
    string name[SIZE];
    int price[SIZE];
    int qua[SIZE];
};                                                            
 void fun_struct(Dannie vvod){
        cout<<"_______Redactor_______"<<endl;
        cout<<"Vvedite nomer tovara:"<<vvod.number<<endl;}                 
 int main() {
    Dannie d={123};
    fun_struct(d);                                                   
     return 0;}
```

2)Пишет две ошибки: 1-  warning character constant too long for its type и подчеркивает 'moloko'.(
предупреждающий символ слишком длинный для своего типа и подчеркивает) Почему?я ведь указала размер массива name[20] и туда вполне должно влезть слово- moloko.
2-определение функции здесь не разрешено до токена '{' , почему не разрешено?
     base.cpp: In function 'void fun_struct(Dannnie)':
     base.cpp:114:12: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
      int main() { - указывает снизу на скобку
     base.cpp:141:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
     } - указывает снизу на скобку

```
void fun_struct(Dannie vvod){
            cout<<"_______Redactor_______"<<endl;
            for(int i=1;i<=2;i++){
            cout<<"Vvedite nomer tovara:"<<vvod.number[i]<<endl;
            cout<<"Vvedite naimenovanie tovara:"<<vvod.name[i]<<endl;}        
     int main() {
        Dannie d={{123},{'moloko'}};
        int test=2;
        for (int i=1;i<=test;i++){
        fun_struct(d[i]);}                                         
        return 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `vvod.number` - массив `int`, вывадится как указатель на первый элемент.
2. `'moloko'` - вы попытались создать **символ** из шести символов. Строки записываются с двойными кавычками.
3. Нет закрывающей функцию `fun_struct` скобки. Это вы увидели бы сразу, если бы хоть чуть-чуть потрудились ворматьировать код, а не делать страшную макаронину...

Посмотрите:

```
void fun_struct(Dannie vvod) {
    cout<<"_______Redactor_______"<<endl;
    for(int i=1;i<=2;i++){
        cout<<"Vvedite nomer tovara:"<<vvod.number[i]<<endl;
        cout<<"Vvedite naimenovanie tovara:"<<vvod.name[i]<<endl;
        }
    int main() {
        Dannie d={{123},{'moloko'}};
        int test=2;
        for (int i=1;i<=test;i++){
            fun_struct(d[i]);
            }
        return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

Ошибку нашла. 
1)

```
void fun_struct(Dannie vvod){
            cout<<"_______Redactor_______"<<endl;
            for(int i=1;i<=2;i++){
            cout<<"Vvedite nomer tovara:"<<vvod.number[i]<<endl;
            cout<<"Vvedite naimenovanie tovara:"<<vvod.name[i]<<endl;} //  нужна еще одна скобка}
```

2)

```
int main() {
        Dannie d={{123},{'moloko'}};
        int test=2;
        for (int i=1;i<=test;i++){
        fun_struct(d[i]);}       //  не правильно вызвала функцию  fun_struct(d)                     
        return 0;}
```

Comment: Что за белиберда написана?

Comment: Самостоятельное изучение структуры в с++